# question about schur canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is an $n\times n$-matrix and it has $n$ orthonormal eigenvectors,

is it true that $U^*AU$ is diagonal? $U$ is an unitary matrix and $U^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $U$.

If it is true, how to prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean here. If $A$ has $n$ orthonormal eigenvectors, then almost by definition it is unitarily diagonalizable. What does this have to do with the Schur canonical form (by which I assume you mean the Schur triangularization)?

Comment: The OP probably meant the columns of $U$ are the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: @EuYu thanks for your reply. Could you give me some links that talk about the unitarily diagonalizable? Especially why A has n orthonormal eigenvectors then it is unitarily diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unitary diagonalization is really the same thing as normal diagonalization, except the eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis instead of a regular basis.

Recall that you diagonalize by forming an eigenbasis $\mathcal{B}$ of some matrix $A$. If the matrix $P$ has columns $\mathcal{B}$ then $P^{-1}AP$ will be diagonal. Now if the basis you took was orthonormal, then it follows that $P$ is not only invertible, but unitary. You have *unitarily* diagonalized $A$.

Of course, this is not always possible. Not all matrices are diagonalizable, and of those that are, still not all are unitarily diagonalizable. But you are *given* that your matrix has an orthonormal set of $n$ eigenvectors which by the above discussion is equivalent to the matrix being unitarily diagonalizable. The condition of being unitarily diagonalizable is equivalent to that of being **normal** in the sense of $AA^* = A^*A$.

Now Schur decomposition is something different, albeit related. Over $\mathcal{C}$ there always exists a unitary matrix $U$ for which $U^*AU = T$ is upper triangular. This is what is typically called the Schur decomposition or Schur triangularization. I assume this is what you mean by "Schur canonical form". It turns out that *if* your matrix $A$ is normal, then the unitary matrix which triangularizes $A$ also diagonalizes $A$. I suspect this is what your question is really asking. In fact this is the standard proof given that a normal matrix is unitarily diagonalizable. I will sketch the proof below.

**Theorem:** Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix. Then $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable if and only if $A$ is normal.

**Proof:** I will sketch a proof for the backwards direction. Suppose that $A$ is normal. Then $AA^* = A^*A$. Let $A$ be triangularized by the unitary matrix $U$. We then have $T=U^*AU$. Now consider
$$T^*T = U^*A^*AU  = U^*AA^*U = TT^*$$
If you compare the diagonal entries of $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ you will see that the equality forces the off-diagonal entries to be zero.